# Devise & MongoMapper & Rails - Cannot see any devise pages (broken routes / actions)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, authentication, devise, mongomapper

I am getting "too many redirects" when I'm trying to access my /users/sign_up page

Devise + MongoMapper + Rails 3.2.13

[image: Too many redirects]

rake routes:

```
                   users GET    /users(.:format)              users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)              users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)          users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)     users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)          users#show
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)          users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)          users#destroy
        new_user_session GET    /users/login(.:format)        devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/login(.:format)        devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/logout(.:format)       devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/reset(.:format)        devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/reset/new(.:format)    devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/reset/edit(.:format)   devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/reset(.:format)        devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)       devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)              devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)      devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)         devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)              devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)              devise/registrations#destroy
                    root        /                             customers#index
               customers GET    /customers(.:format)          customers#index
                         POST   /customers(.:format)          customers#create
            new_customer GET    /customers/new(.:format)      customers#new
           edit_customer GET    /customers/:id/edit(.:format) customers#edit
                customer GET    /customers/:id(.:format)      customers#show
                         PUT    /customers/:id(.:format)      customers#update
                         DELETE /customers/:id(.:format)      customers#destroy
```

Rails server console just spits this out over and over:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-24 21:10:01 -0800
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"sign_in"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
```

I read on their ReadMe that Devise is supposed to make some helper methods in my controller - I don't see any but the standard 7 from the generator.

It seems like it's trying to login as "sign_in" which I certainly didn't instruct it to do - this is a brand new Rails application basically just with one model - User - and one model - Customer - and absolutely no data or any other files yet.  Literally just trying to get this Devise login page to render - or signup page - or any page.

Here is my entire routes.rb file right now:

```
  resources :users

  devise_for :users

  root :to => "customers#index"

  resources :customers
```

**This happens when I have before_filter authenticate_user! in my Users Controller**

So when I take that line out - and I just try to hit /users/sign_up - I get the following:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil}
```

It's supposed to redirect here:

```
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)         devise/registrations#edit
```

The controller action is :

```
def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

And of course - since there's nothing in my DB at all - @user is nil now - is that the issue?

How do people get Devise started???  I've never once successfully got this stupid thing to work.

Comment: Ok the answer is the devise_for :users should be ABOVE resources :users in routes.rb.  I found that from the suggested reading that StackOverflow showed me right as I was setting my title and about to save this - so someone else can post that as an Answer and get credit :)

Answer (score 0):

You should have the line:

`devise_for :users`

above the line:

`resources :users`

That is because you need to set up the Devise resources for a model before anything else.

What you could also do is remap the Devise routes to you own. You'd **replace** `resources :users` with a `devise_scope` block. Here is the [Documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/#Configuring_routes) for it.